# Is there a way to use interrupt-driven GPIO input through the sysfs interface without a race condition?

Tags: gpio, sysfs

I want to use the GPIO pins to wait for a button-press without using a CPU spin loop. My preferred way of using the GPIO pins is via the sysfs interface at `/sys/class/gpio`, but it seems to me that there is an inherent race condition in doing so. Namely, if I understand the sysfs interface to GPIO correctly, it seems one must go through the following sequence:

1. Read the `value` file to see whether the desired condition holds true.
2. If it does not (the usual case for the first iteration), poll the value file for `POLLPRI` to sleep until it changes state, and repeat from step 1.

However, in this procedure, there is a window of opportunity between steps 1 and 2 such that the button is not yet pressed when the value is read, but then pushed right before entering doing the `poll` call, in which case this particular button press would effectively be missed.

I mean, I realize that a low-frequency event like button presses doesn't really have a high probability of triggering this race condition, but there are certainly more high-frequency events that could, and even regardless of that, it just seems ugly. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Not to try to talk you out of your [preference for `sysfs`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193096), but [it's been deprecated](https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-sysfs-gpio/issues/38) and may not be around much longer.

Comment: @Seamus: I'm fine with being talked out of sysfs access, I just don't quite know what the alternative would be, except direct register access, which seems a bit ugly in comparison to using user-space interfaces.

Comment: Follow the first link in my comment above - there are at least two good libraries, and that link discusses them. `pigpio` is one of those libraries, and I see @joan has already answered, so you're in good hands.

Comment: I think the real issue here is the implication that you have to wait to start polling *after* a point when the button press could occur, which implies a significant design flaw.

Comment: @goldilocks: Not sure what you're talking about. There is always a particular point in time where the process enters the `poll` call, and my question is about how to coordinate that with a point when I know that the button is not already pressed.

Comment: Ok, it is a semi-reasonable paranioa, but: Poll only the edge you want to trigger on, or use separate fds for rising and falling.  Then you know what the state is without having to check it, and there is no need to know the state before the *first* poll.  After that, the system buffers file data/events for userspace processes -- for example, if you are reading from a normal open file that is being appended to by another process, and using `poll` to wait for the new data...

Comment: ...there's no race condition WRT what happens when you are processing that data and more is added before you call `poll` again *using the same open fd*: When you do, it will return immediately with that data , because that event has been buffered on the open handle.  In the sysfs gpio case, the event is actually a modification of the content, which is why if you want to read the value you need to either re-open the file or (probably more robust) rewind (`lseek()`) as per...

Comment: ...[the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt).  But again, you don't need to do that polling one edge (I suppose it is true that between `poll()` and `lseek()` the value could have changed several times, but not because a person is repeatedly pushing a button at 500 Hz). As long as you keep the same fd events will be cued for processing in userspace *even if the content of the file is not retained* (but you don't need that anyway if you are polling a single edge).

Comment: **Note that in the end this will all work poorly unless you deal with bounce, and there is no alternate methodogy to get out of that!**  A human button push lasts at least 50-100 ms, during which time both edges will trigger multiple times.

Comment: @goldilocks: Doesn't the fact that you're composing such a lengthy reply indicate that the question is about a general valid principle rather than a local problem which cannot be reproduced, and that you should post that as an answer instead?

Comment: The real close reason was more like "smells like [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)", but the mechanism is cookie cutter.  My issue is it's several years old and unlikely at this point, IMO, to generate anything very productive -- sticking to my position that it is a chimerical problem.   But I won't shove that down anyone's throat any further, so fair enough.  It would be interesting to read how *you* solved/got over this...

Answer (score 3):

You should probably think about migrating to the new gpiochip interface for any new software.  One improvement is that it gives you the likely time of GPIO level changes.

I have done pretty much what you describe with sysfs without noticing a problem.  I suspect that once you have set the GPIO as an input and given an edge the system is primed to respond to level changes.  That may be why I consume any prior interrupt in this code.

I suggest having a look in wiringPi or (my) pigpio which both have sysfs interrupt code.

```c
/* 2014-07-06
   wfi.c

   gcc -o wfi wfi.c

   ./wfi [gpio]
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define GPIO 4

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char str[256];
   struct timeval tv;
   struct pollfd pfd;
   int fd, gpio;
   char buf[8];

   /*
      Prior calls assumed.
      sudo sh -c "echo 4      >/sys/class/gpio/export"
      sudo sh -c "echo in     >/sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction"
      sudo sh -c "echo rising >/sys/class/gpio/gpio4/edge"
   */

   if (argc > 1) gpio = atoi(argv[1]);
   else          gpio = GPIO;

   sprintf(str, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio);

   if ((fd = open(str, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed, gpio %d not exported.\n", gpio);
      exit(1);
   }

   pfd.fd = fd;

   pfd.events = POLLPRI;

   lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);    /* consume any prior interrupt */
   read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);

   poll(&pfd, 1, -1);         /* wait for interrupt */

   lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);    /* consume interrupt */
   read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);

   exit(0);
}
```

I didn't set up the edge and direction within the above code because I wanted the program to work without running with root permissions.

Comment: "*The new gpiochip interface*", you say? Does this refer to the `/dev/gpiochip*` files? Are they preferable to the sysfs interface? I've been trying to find documentation about it, but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Have a search for a user space interface called libgpiod.  E.g. https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/11/03/learn-more-about-linuxs-new-gpio-user-space-subsystem-libgpiod/

Comment: i tried do it in python, polling on 1 works as expected, but polling then 0 fires every 0.00007 seconds

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, there is a simple bash way for GPIO interrupt controlled read via sysfs interface:

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
echo both > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/edge
```

and now the **blocking** wait for change interrupt for the resp. value (inotifywait will block until the value will change, e.g. falling or raising, but this will work only, if the edge has been set).

```
inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
# here you may start your handling for a change of value
```

you may change the edge from both to falling or raising only, whatever you want. You can write a blocking watchdog script for every GPIO you want to watch with the lines above in an endless loop. Have fun.
The gpio setting part above must be run by root, but only once at startup or any other suitable place. The inotify loop below could be run by any user.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not seeing how this saves the race condition that the question asks about. This way, surely there's an opportunity for the GPIO values to changes between checking them to see if it's time to block, and actually blocking?

Comment: It's worth observing that a button press (as in, a button pressed by a human being): 1. Does not take place instantaneously, and will last several orders of magnitude more time than that between "read" and "poll" ; 2. Involves multiple changes of state, unless we mean "button down when the user may hold it indefinitely"; 3.  Realistically, involves a lot more than just two changes of state due to bounce, and if you are not dealing with bounce (it is clear you are not) you have a defective, highly error prone system to start with.